# CSS menu and text embedded...codepen.io/foukton/pen/zYvJEzz

Tags: html, css

I'm a young french who's making his first Portfolio..but I don’t know much about CSS...if someone can help me to remove the  and all texts from my navigation bar correctly?

Here's my codepen.io : `codepen.io/foukton/pen/zYvJEzz`

Thank you in advance for your comments! 
Matteo

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from `ul {...}` and add `#bloc_page { position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 1 }` and `.block { margin-top: 5rem }` to your CSS. That should get you going. Logic: stick the navigation parent to the top of the viewport and move the content container down (in this case 5rem) by adding some space on top. While you're at it: add a closing `</section>` to your HTML. How about checking out [Html5up](https://html5up.net), download a nice template and use that as a starting point? Furthermore, don't just post 'have a look at' link, but post a [reprex]... Bon Chance!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, as you can see on my codepen i apply your advice and now it works ! Great site html5up I will keep it under the elbow. Unfortunately our teacher does not let us use CMS or any templates... This is my first time ! Last question, I noticed that by adding some `.block { margin-top: 5rem }`, my "galaxy" background was not spread all over the page. What is the setting to apply to make it fill my entire site?

Comment: Check the width/height ratio of your browser window and the JPEG. Do they match? Now check [w3schools: background-size](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and [w3schools: background-position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp). The spreading has nothing to do with the `.block` rule, has it...